# Vue.js how to display a default value in a selector as well as sort the options?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an application with vue.js and I run into a problem, I have a selector with options in the `options` array.
But when I display the page there is no value in this selector, basically I would like it to take the first base value but I have no idea how to do it.
Before I do that I would also like to sort the options array against the sorted array.
Thanks in advance.

**Code :** https://codepen.io/pronicio/pen/eYGJjMP

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected : {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: '',
    options: [ 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    sorted: [ 'B', 'C']
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I would also like to sort the options array against the sorted array.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of vue in your codepan. Update the version. You can add the selected option into the `mounted` hook. If you get the options by any api. Choose the selected one after getting the response.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: '',
    options: [ 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    sorted: [ 'B', 'C', 'A']
  },
  mounted(){
    this.selected =  this.options[0]
    
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected : {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```